# regex is not working with populate in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

Inside the product schema i stored  category and brand objectId,if i search by product name it returning products but if search by category name or brand name not returning the data.I added category and brand ref in the product schema.

this is code:

```
let query = { isDeleted: false };

if (search) {
  const sanitizedSearch = search.replace(/^\s+/, ''); 
  query["$or"] = [
    { "name": { $regex: sanitizedSearch, $options: "i" } }, 
    { "category.name": { $regex: sanitizedSearch, $options: "i" } },
    { "brand.name": { $regex: sanitizedSearch, $options: "i" } }, 
  ];
}


const data = await Product.find(query)
  .populate("category").populate("brand")
  .sort({ item_id: -1 })
  .skip((page - 1) * limit)
  .limit(limit);

const totalProducts = await Product.countDocuments(query);
const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalProducts / limit);
```

Comment: Populate is performed after the query is executed so `category.name` and `brand.name` are not part of the document at the time when the regex is performed.

Comment: How can i filter data according brand and category

Comment: You would need to perform an aggregation query where you populate first then do the regex match. This has performance downsides.